# Tokenizing Chinese text with keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer

Tags: python, keras, nlp, tokenize, cjk

`keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer` doesn't work correctly with Chinese text. How can I modify it to work on Chinese text?

```py
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
def fit_get_tokenizer(data, max_words):
    tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=max_words, filters='!"#%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~\t\n')
    tokenizer.fit_on_texts(data)
    return tokenizer
tokenizer = fit_get_tokenizer(df.sentence,max_words=150000)
print('Total number of words: ', len(tokenizer.word_index))
vocabulary_inv = {}
for word in tokenizer.word_index:
    vocabulary_inv[tokenizer.word_index[word]] = word
print(vocabulary_inv)
```

Comment: can you provide some dummy data? and also show why exactly you mean the tokenizer does not work correctly?

Comment: from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
def fit_get_tokenizer(data, max_words):
    tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=max_words, filters='!"#%&()*+, -./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~\t\n',oov_token="<UTF-8>")
    tokenizer.fit_on_texts(data)
    return tokenizer
tokenizer = fit_get_tokenizer(df.sentence,max_words=150000)
print("Total number of words: ", len(tokenizer.word_index))
vocabulary_inv = {}
for word in tokenizer.word_index:
    vocabulary_inv[tokenizer.word_index[word]] = word
print(vocabulary_inv)

Comment: I input an English dataset( df.sentence contains 4/5 lines of sentences) it can seperate each word correctly but if I put chinese dataset in that place it takes whole sentences as a word)

Comment: English corpus example- nasa, in preparation for a spacewalk on saturday, has devised makeshift snorkels that would allow an astronaut in a spacesuit to continue breathing even if a sudden water leak should fill the helmet, as happened to an italian astronaut who almost drowned in july....
result i get -> giances', 30884: 'maniacal', 30885: 'swans', 30886: 'electro', 30887: 'vestiges', 30888: 'shuffles', 30889: 'lorton', 30890: 'scribbling',

Comment: chinese corpus - '强噪声环境引起的光束抖动及其指向稳定性问题研究具有重要的理论和实际意义。该硕士论文通过实验方法研究噪声引起的光束抖动机制和规律。取得了以下的几点创新成果：1）设计了一套模拟噪声诱导光束抖动的实验方案，用来研究噪声环境下光学系统光束传输方向变化的规律。2）实验结果表明：光束抖动幅值和噪声强度有关
result:- 36: '718', 37: '关于论文选题意义、主要结论、计算和实验', 38: '论文选题是否有意义？主要结论是否正确？计算和实验是否可靠？', 39: '论文是否具有新见解，主要表现在哪些方面？', 40: '请明确填写结论意见及综合评价。', 41: 'hd', 42: '对论文的理论、实用价值和质量的评价。',

Comment: Please edit your question with all this information.

Comment: I tried to put details a=in the body but it wouldn't let me. I put the infos in breif summary as well

Comment: I tried to put spaced Chinese sentences contained in a list where each element is a chinese sentence(propersly spaced) but then it gave me this error:

Comment: expected string or bytes-like object. I saw in the documentation this Tokenizer can take list as input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

````
def fit_get_tokenizer(data, max_words):
    c=[]
    for i in range(len(data)):
        a = []
        text_tokens = re.findall(r'(.*?[？\ . \ ！)。])\s?', data[i])
        for i, j in enumerate(text_tokens):

            seg_list = jieba.lcut(j, cut_all=False)
            sen = " ".join(seg_list)
            a.append(sen)
        for i in a:
            c.append(i)
    tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=max_words)
    tokenizer.fit_on_texts(c)
    return tokenizer ```

If anyone going thorough Chinese text segmentation. I used regular expression to extract sentence from Chinese paragraph. Then I have used jieba(instead of NLTK) to get perfect word tokens and getting it ready keras Tokenizer.
````

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Since I cannot post Chinese texts in SO, I will demonstrate how to do it with English sentences, but the same applies to Chinese:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
text = ['This is a chinese sentence', 
         'This is another chinese sentence']
tokenizer = tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer(num_words=50, char_level = False)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(text)
print(tokenizer.word_index)
```

```
{'this': 1, 'is': 2, 'chinese': 3, 'sentence': 4, 'a': 5, 'another': 6}
```

Make sure you have a list of Chinese space-separated sentences and it should work correctly. Using a list of lists will lead to unexpected behavior.

Comment: It's working now. Thank you